# does retention policy gets applied on all measurements in a DB even if it is not set to default

Tags: influxdb

if a retention policy is created in a database and it is not set to default, will it keep deleting data form all the measurements from that database as per the specified duration?
E.g.
there is a database called testDB and inside it there are four measurements namely, testMeas, testMeas1, testMeas2 and testMeas3.

now if i execute the following command:
**create retention policy “testRet” on “testDB” duration 1h replication 1**

and then i do:
**select first(*) into testRet.testMeas3 from testMeas**

will it start deleting data which is older than one hour from every measurement or only from testMeas3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will delete data from only testMeas3.

You can create multiple retention policies for a database and use different  retention policies for different measurements. Each measurement use its own retention policy to retain the data.

Comment: Hi @darkDragon

can i create a retention policy and make one existing measurement to fall under it.
For E.g.
there is a measurement m1 inside a db testDB.
now i create a new retention named r1.
how can i make m1 fall under r1